# Javascript date of birth conundrum

Tags: javascript, html

I need to validate a primitive date of birth field input in the format of:

'mmmyyyy'

Where the first 3 characters of the string must be an acceptable 3-letter abbreviation of the months of the year. 
**It can be lowercase, or uppercase, or a mix of any so long as it spells out jan or feb or mar etc etc etc.** 
There is no built-in method that I am aware of that has a ready array of this specific format of a month to be able compare against user input. I was thinking that I could maybe use the `localeCompare()` method in a for loop to test if the output is not 0 then append an error message accordingly.

Comment: Is all you're needing is to check the first three characters? `'JaN1975'.toLowerCase().substring(0,3)`?

Comment: this may also be helpful lib you can use http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function dateTester() {
   var d = new Date(),
      i,
      mo = [],
      moIsValid;
   for (i = 0; i < 12; i += 1) {
      d.setMonth(i);
      mo.push(d.toLocaleString().split(' ')[1].substr(0, 3));
   }
   return new RegExp('^(' + mo.join('|') + ')', 'i');
}

var moIsValid = dateTester();
alert(moIsValid.test('fEb1992'));
```

If you don't want the user's current locale name for the days to be valid, then just switch `toLocaleString()` to `toString()`. But then, why don't you just do this instead:

```
var moIsValid = /^(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)/i;
alert(moIsValid.test('fEb1992'));
```

Comment: +1 for the regex check, which is probably the most straight-forward, assuming locality isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you just really, *really* want to check a month with a "dynamic" test, you can do:

```
var months = 'jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec';

months.indexOf('JaN1975'.toLowerCase().substring(0,3)
```

Checking with:

```
console.log(months.indexOf('JaN1975'.toLowerCase().substring(0,3)) != -1);
console.log(months.indexOf('oct1975'.toLowerCase().substring(0,3)) != -1);
console.log(months.indexOf('FEB1975'.toLowerCase().substring(0,3)) != -1);
console.log(months.indexOf('Ja1975'.toLowerCase().substring(0,3)) != -1);
console.log(months.indexOf('091975'.toLowerCase().substring(0,3)) != -1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ELMFu/

Gives:

```
true
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: No, I'm referring to IE 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, and who knows what else.

Comment: I don't have those original browsers, but using Developer Tools Browser Mode, IE7, 8 and 9 all work. Anybody catering to older IE versions than that need to have a specific reason to do, in my view. In that case, switch it to a string, whatever.

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong information. Doesn't work in 8, which is not *that* old.

Comment: I found [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679977%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), which does say that pre-IE9 doesn't work. So. It *will* work with a string... To a point. The problem there becomes `'b,m1975'` would pass, without filtering. So that would be less preferable than the regex check you demonstrate.

Comment: You can always roll your own indexOf or pull the official version from mozilla!

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(str.replace(/(\D+)(\d+)/, "1 $1 $2"))
```

EDIT: use `isNaN` to test whether the date failed to parse.

Comment: How does that help? How do you test if this is valid? Also, this works with "February1997" as well, which may not be desired.

Comment: @ErikE `new Date` returns `Invalid Date` if the date is invalid. And yes, I was making assumptions as to the format of the string.

Comment: is that "Invalid Date" a string, so you can say `new Date(...) === 'Invalid Date'`?

Comment: @ErikE `new Date ('x').toString(); // "Invalid Date"`, so yes, you can do that

Answer (score 0):

I like this concise function for validating your input:

```
var months = "janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec";
function validate(dateString) {
    return dateString.length == 7 &&
           !(months.indexOf(dateString.substr(0,3).toLowerCase()) % 3) &&
           isFinite(dateString.substr(3));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/NR3aG/

Comment: If you're going to do a literal string, why don't you just use [my 2-line method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11855662/57611)?